# Get Date PHPExcel Format

Tags: php, phpexcel, getdate

I'm trying to get a date (PHPExcel Format) from the cell (C24), but what I'm getting just this:

The cell (C24) has the following formula: =G2-(WEEKDAY(G2)-2)

```
echo "Calc Value:".$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C24')->getCalculatedValue()."\n";
echo "Format Value:".$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C24')->getFormattedValue()."\n";
echo "Value:".$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C24')->getValue()."\n";
echo "Value:".$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C24')->getOldCalculatedValue()."\n";

//Output:
Calc Value:#VALUE!
Format Value:#VALUE!
Value:=G2-(WEEKDAY(G2)-2)
Value:
```

I expected to get the PHPExcel Date Format, something like '48223'.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: So give us some clues.... what is in cell G2?

Comment: And note that it is not a PHPExcel date format.... it's a MS Excel serialized timestamp..... we didn't invent it to be ornery and make things difficult, Microsoft did

Comment: Ok, MS Excel timestamp.... go ahead...

C2 = current date... just '02/10/2017' (brazilian format).